# Unable to select option from drop down(Tried all ways) in selenium

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, xpath, testng

I am trying to select the option from the drop down menu. But it is not getting selected. The test case passes without any error and without selecting the option. Since it is HTML drop down I have used click. I tried Select class but it did not work. The site is https://demoqa.com/automation-practice-form/
The code I have written here is

```
>     JavascriptExecutor js=(JavascriptExecutor)driver;
>     Actions act=new Actions(driver);
>     js.executeScript("window.scrollBy(0,500)");
>     WebElement we=driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@id='state']"));
>     act.moveToElement(we).click().build().perform();
>     WebElement we3=driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[contains(.,'Uttar
> Pradesh')]/following-sibling::div/descendant::input"));
        act.moveToElement(we3).click(we3).build().perform();
```

your help is solicited. Thanks

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its different element u need to click after sending keys as "Uttar Pradesh"

Use below code

```
new WebDriverWait(driver , 20).until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.xpath("//input[@id='react-select-3-input']"))).sendKeys("Uttar");
new WebDriverWait(driver ,20).until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.xpath("//div[contains(@id,'react-select')]"))).click();
```

Comment: How are we using sendKeys() for elementToBeClickable method. I thought we can use only click in conjunction with elementToBeClickable ? I had used it in conjunction with click() but it had not worked. Could you please explain your code

Comment: even if you use sendkeys and click in conjunction as u said, it will still work.. u just need to use correct xpath

Answer (score 0):

The code below worked for me.

```
    WebDriver Driver = new ChromeDriver();
    Driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
    String url = "https://demoqa.com/automation-practice-form";
    Driver.get(url);
    WebElement products=Driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@id='react-select-3-input']"));
    products.sendKeys("Uttar Pradesh");
    products.sendKeys(Keys.ARROW_DOWN);
    products.sendKeys(Keys.ENTER);
    System.out.println("completed");
```